# Background Job Manager for Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, backgroundworker

Does anyone know of a background job manager that works with Rails 3? I have heard of Starling and Workling but I do not see a fork for Rails 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used [this article](http://www.dixis.com/?p=335) to get delayed_job (a common rails 2 gem for queueing jobs to be done later) running on rails 3.  The [collectiveidea branch of delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) has rails 3 support and works great.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for a background-job worker ?
for simple usage i suggest delayed_job 
https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/

Resque instead is more powerfull (It's used for github background job) but complicated.
https://github.com/defunkt/resque

bye

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the railscast: beanstalkd and stalker: http://railscasts.com/episodes/243-beanstalkd-and-stalker

Answer (score 0):

spawn is fine if you just want to run some code in a seperate thread and just forget about it.
https://github.com/tra/spawn